# Run individual nose-parameterized tests

Tags: pycharm, nose, nose-parameterized

I am working on a Django project, and we are using nose-parameterized library. I can see all of the parameterized tests in the runner if I run the full class, but then if I try to run just by right clicking the test name, and clicking run or debug, pycharm fails to inject the parameters.

any ideas on how to get this workflow to work? as a workaround, i am making individual data driven test cases in single classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can run those parameterized test cases using:

```
--test= modulename/method name
```

e.g

```
nosetests -v test_file_name.py --test=modulename/method name,modulename2
```

Refer this link
http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html

Comment: ah, gotcha. makes sense